# Can we instantiate an abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, class, object, abstract

During one of my interview, I was asked "If we can instantiate an abstract class?"

My reply was "No. we can't". But, interviewer told me "Wrong, we can."

I argued a bit on this. Then he told me to try this myself at home.

```
abstract class my {
    public void mymethod() {
        System.out.print("Abstract");
    }
}

class poly {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        my m = new my() {};
        m.mymethod();
    }
}
```

Here, I'm creating instance of my class and calling method of abstract class. Can anyone please explain this to me? Was I really wrong during my interview?

Comment: Although only slightly related, one can perhaps instantiate an abstract class in C++: if you derive a non-abstract class `B` from an abstract one `A`, _during the part of construction_ of `B` instance, which consist running `A`'s constructor, the object's runtime type is actually `A`. Only temporary however.

Comment: @Vlad: In C++ we have the concept "fully abstract" and "not fully abstract". In "fully abstract" we can't do the object creation.

Comment: @jWeavers: The example he has given is totally wrong. You should have asked "then what is the use of abstract class" from him. If you are extending it, then why are you creating an instance of the extended class? It is a completely new object, where you end up with no data..

Comment: Or may be the interviewer wanted to check how confident you are about your statement against what he proposed!

Comment: He lied to you.  You dropped the ball when you failed to point out that isn't what this code does and explain what anonymous subclasses are.  He probably knew that already and wanted to see if you knew.

Comment: This wasn't a quiz show, but a job interview, right? So what if Java, or C++, allowed instantiating abstract classes? You wouldn't do it, because it's not a clever thing to do. In Objective-C, abstract classes are only abstract by convention, and instantiating them is a bug.

Comment: This is like asking can you write Java code in JSP? For everything, there is a purpose and what would you achieve instantiating an Abstract class and even if you do, that's a wrong way. I believe your interviewer as simply in no mood to select you.

Answer (score 785, accepted):

> Here, i'm creating instance of my class

No, you are not creating the instance of your abstract class here. Rather you are creating an instance of an *anonymous subclass* of your abstract class. And then you are invoking the method on your *abstract class* reference pointing to *subclass object*.

This behaviour is clearly listed in [JLS - Section # 15.9.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9): -

> If the class instance creation expression ends in a class body, then
>   the class being instantiated is an anonymous class. Then:
>
> - If T denotes a class, then an anonymous direct subclass of the class    named by T is declared. It is a compile-time error if the
>     class    denoted by T is a final class.
> - If T denotes an interface, then an anonymous direct subclass of    Object that implements the interface named by T is declared.
> - In either case, the body of the subclass is the ClassBody given in    the class instance creation expression.
> - **The class being instantiated is the anonymous subclass.**

Emphasis mine.

Also, in [JLS - Section # 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), you can read about the *Object Creation Process*. I'll quote one statement from that here: -

> Whenever a new class instance is created, memory space is allocated
>   for it with room for all the instance variables declared in the class
>   type and all the instance variables declared in each superclass of the
>   class type, including all the instance variables that may be hidden.
>
> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the
>   result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new
>   object using the following procedure:

You can read about the complete procedure on the link I provided.

---

To practically see that the class being instantiated is an *Anonymous SubClass*, you just need to compile both your classes. Suppose you put those classes in two different files:

**My.java:**

```
abstract class My {
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.print("Abstract");
    }
}
```

**Poly.java:**

```
class Poly extends My {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        My m = new My() {};
        m.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Now, compile both your source files:

```
javac My.java Poly.java
```

Now in the directory where you compiled the source code, you will see the following class files:

```
My.class
Poly$1.class  // Class file corresponding to anonymous subclass
Poly.class
```

See that class - `Poly$1.class`. It's the class file created by the compiler corresponding to the anonymous subclass you instantiated using the below code:

```
new My() {};
```

So, it's clear that there is a different class being instantiated. It's just that, that class is given a name only after compilation by the compiler.

In general, all the anonymous subclasses in your class will be named in this fashion:

```
Poly$1.class, Poly$2.class, Poly$3.class, ... so on
```

Those numbers denote the order in which those anonymous classes appear in the enclosing class.

Comment: @coders. Exact answer is: - You can't instantiate your abstract class, however you can instantiate a concrete subclass of your abstract class.

Comment: In one line you can say:-  You can never instantiate an abstract class. That's the purpose of an abstract class.

Comment: It's sounds like the interviewer was more invested in his answer than he was in yours...

Comment: According to [another comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670991/interview-can-we-instantiate-abstract-class#comment18765570_13671010) (with a [JLS reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.6)), "An object is said to be an instance of its class and of all superclasses of its class" - therefore, aren't we actually technically creating an instance of the abstract class here? i.e. instantiating the abstract class?

Comment: @A.R.S. I'd say that there's a difference between being an `instance of` and `instantiating`. You only instantiate one class, while that object you create can be an instance of multiple classes due to inheritance.

Comment: @A.R.S... Actually, we don't create an instance of super classes. Object is created by `new` operator, and not by constructor. Invocation is constructor is just required to initialize the state of the object created by `new`. So, what happens is, `new` operator creates an instance of the class it is linked to - (In this case, the anonymous subclass) of abstract class, and then calls all the super class constructor to initialize it's state.

Comment: Agreed. It is an instance of an anonymous subclass of the abstract class. You do not need to believe my words. Just check the generate class files and you will find poly$1.class which are the bytecodes of the anonymous subclass! Ergo, there is a third class here!

Comment: @RohitJain: why did you `extends My`? Its probably not needed for your great answer.

Comment: @RohitJain Is it allowed for an `abstract` class (in this case `My`) to have only concrete method(s) [method(s) with definition]? Any class must have at least one `abstract` method to become `abstract` right?

Comment: @AbhinavVutukuri No. All methods can be concrete in an abstract class.

Comment: `New` keyword: is using to pass an instance of **A CONCRETE** class to a defined variable. a concrete class is a class that implements all of its methods, so --> you **NEVER can use new** with **abstract** and **interfaces**. but **you can** define a variable **with the type of them** and then **assign them** an instance of **a concrete class**.

Answer (score 98):

The above instantiates an anonymous inner class which is a subclass of the `my` abstract class. It's not strictly equivalent to instantiating the abstract class itself. OTOH, every subclass instance is an instance of all its super classes and interfaces, so most abstract classes are indeed instantiated by instantiating one of their concrete subclasses.

If the interviewer just said "wrong!" without explaining, and gave this example, as a unique counterexample, I think he doesn't know what he's talking about, though.

Comment: ***Strictly*** speaking, the abstract superclass is not instantiated. It's constructor is called to initialize instance variables.

Comment: Yes it is: `subclassInstance instanceof SuperClass` would return true, so the object is an instance of the superclass, which means the superclass has been instanciated. But that's just semantic nitpicking.

Comment: Could be semantics indeed. Java defines *instantiation* in terms of creating objects via the ***new*** keyword (which ofc you cannot do with an abstract class). But of course the concrete subclass will report correctly that its an instance of every member of its parent hierarchy.

Comment: [paragraph 4.12.6 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.6) says: "An object is said
to be an instance of its class and of all superclasses of its class.".

Answer (score 92):

`= my() {};` means that there's an anonymous implementation, not simple instantiation of an object, which should have been : `= my()`. You can never instantiate an abstract class.

Answer (score 31):

Just observations you could make:

1. Why `poly` extends `my`? This is useless...
2. What is the result of the compilation? Three files: `my.class`, `poly.class` and `poly$1.class`
3. If we can instantiate an abstract class like that, we can instantiate an interface too... weird...

**Can we instantiate an abstract class?**

No, we can't. What we can do is, create an anonymous class (that's the third file) and instantiate it.

**What about a super class instantiation?**

The abstract super class is not instantiated by **us** but by java.

**EDIT: Ask him to test this**

```
public static final void main(final String[] args) {
    final my m1 = new my() {
    };
    final my m2 = new my() {
    };
    System.out.println(m1 == m2);

    System.out.println(m1.getClass().toString());
    System.out.println(m2.getClass().toString());

}
```

output is:

```
false
class my$1
class my$2
```

Comment: +1 for observation 3: e.g., we can do `Serializable s = new Serializable() {};` (which is pretty useless) and if tagged onto your code would give `class my$3` (or whatever enclosing class and number)

Answer (score 20):

You can simply answers, in just one line

> **No**, you can never instance Abstract Class

But, interviewer still not agree, then you can tell him/her

> all you can do is, you can create an Anonymous Class.

And, according to Anonymous class, **class declared and instantiate at the same place/line**

So, it might be possible that, interviewer would be interested to check your confidence level and how much you know about the OOPs .

Answer (score 18):

The technical part has been well-covered in the other answers, and it mainly ends in:
 "He is wrong, he doesn't know stuff, ask him to join SO and get it all cleared :)"

I would like to address the fact(which has been mentioned in other answers) that this might be a [stress-question](http://faze.ca/the-stress-interview-dealing-with-it/) and is an important tool for many interviewers to know more about you and how do you react to difficult and unusual situations. By giving you incorrect codes, he *probably* wanted to see if you argued back. To know whether you have the confidence to stand up against your seniors in situations similar to this.

P.S: I don't know why but I have a feeling that the interviewer has read this post.

Answer (score 14):

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed. [See This Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

The best example is

Although **Calender class has a abstract method getInstance()**, but when you say `Calendar calc=Calendar.getInstance();`

**calc is referring to the class instance of class GregorianCalendar as "GregorianCalendar extends Calendar** "

Infact **annonymous inner type**  **allows you to create a no-name subclass of the abstract class** and an instance of this.

Answer (score 13):

**Technical Answer**

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated - this is by definition and design.

From the JLS, Chapter 8. Classes:

> *A named class may be declared abstract (§8.1.1.1) and must be declared
>   abstract if it is incompletely implemented; such a class cannot be
>   instantiated, but can be extended by subclasses.*

From JSE 6 java doc for Classes.newInstance():

> *InstantiationException - if this Class represents an abstract class, an interface, an array
>   class, a primitive type, or void; or if the class has no nullary constructor; or if the 
>   instantiation fails for some other reason.*

You can, of course, instantiate a concrete subclass of an abstract class (including an anonymous subclass) and also carry out a typecast of an object reference to an abstract type.

**A Different Angle On This - Teamplay & Social Intelligence:**

This sort of technical misunderstanding happens frequently in the real world when we deal with complex technologies and legalistic specifications.

"People Skills" can be more important here than "Technical Skills".  If competitively and aggressively trying to prove your side of the argument, then you could be theoretically right, but you could also do more damage in having a fight / damaging "face" / creating an enemy than it is worth.  Be reconciliatory and understanding in resolving your differences.  Who knows - maybe you're "both right" but working off slightly different meanings for terms??

Who knows - though not likely, it is possible the interviewer deliberately introduced a small conflict/misunderstanding to put you into a challenging situation and see how you behave emotionally and socially.  Be gracious and constructive with colleagues, follow advice from seniors, and follow through after the interview to resolve any challenge/misunderstanding - via email or phone call.  Shows you're motivated and detail-oriented.

Answer (score 7):

It is a well-established fact that `abstract class` can **not** be instantiated as everyone answered.

When the program defines anonymous class, the compiler actually creates a new class with different name (has the pattern `EnclosedClassName$n` where `n` is the anonymous class number)

So if you decompile this Java class you will find the code as below:

my.class

```
abstract class my { 
    public void mymethod() 
    { 
        System.out.print("Abstract"); 
    }
}
```

poly$1.class (the generated class of the "anonymous class")

```
class poly$1 extends my 
{
}
```

ploly.cass

```
public class poly extends my
{
    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        my m = new poly.1(); // instance of poly.1 class NOT the abstract my class

        m.mymethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**About Abstract Classes**

- Cannot create object of an abstract class
- Can create variables (can behave like datatypes)
- If a child can not override at least of one abstract method of the parent, then child also becomes abstract
- Abstract classes are useless without child classes

The purpose of an abstract class is to behave like a base. In inheritance hierarchy you will see abstract classes towards the top.

Answer (score 4):

Extending a class doesn't mean that you are instantiating the class.  Actually, in your case you are creating an instance of the subclass.

I am pretty sure that abstract classes do not allow initiating. So, I'd say no: you can't instantiate an abstract class. But, you can extend it / inherit it.

You can't directly instantiate an abstract class. But it doesn't mean that you can't get an instance of class (not actully an instance of original abstract class) indirectly. I mean you can not instantiate the orginial abstract class, but you can:

1. Create an empty class
2. Inherit it from abstract class
3. Instantiate the dervied class

So you get access to all the methods and properties in an abstract class via the derived class instance.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't instantite an abstract class.We instantiate only anonymous class.In abstract class we declare abstract methods and define concrete methods only.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to instantiate an abstract class. 
What you really can do, has implement some common methods in an abstract class and let others unimplemented (declaring them abstract) and let the concrete descender implement them depending on their needs. 
Then you can make a factory, which returns an instance of this abstract class (actually his implementer). In the factory you then decide, which implementer to choose. This is known as a factory design pattern:

```
   public abstract class AbstractGridManager {
        private LifecicleAlgorithmIntrface lifecicleAlgorithm;
        // ... more private fields

        //Method implemented in concrete Manager implementors 
        abstract public Grid initGrid();

        //Methods common to all implementors
        public Grid calculateNextLifecicle(Grid grid){
            return this.getLifecicleAlgorithm().calculateNextLifecicle(grid);
        }

        public LifecicleAlgorithmIntrface getLifecicleAlgorithm() {
            return lifecicleAlgorithm;
        }
        public void setLifecicleAlgorithm(LifecicleAlgorithmIntrface lifecicleAlgorithm) {
            this.lifecicleAlgorithm = lifecicleAlgorithm;
        }
        // ... more common logic and getters-setters pairs
    }
```

The concrete implementer only needs to implement the methods declared as abstract, but will have access to the logic implemented in those classes in an abstract class, which are not declared abstract:

```
public class FileInputGridManager extends AbstractGridManager {

private String filePath;

//Method implemented in concrete Manager implementors 
abstract public Grid initGrid();

public class FileInputGridManager extends AbstractGridManager {

    private String filePath;

    //Method implemented in concrete Manager implementors 
    abstract public Grid initGrid();

    public Grid initGrid(String filePath) {
        List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<>();
        char[] chars;
        File file = new File(filePath); // for example foo.txt
        // ... more logic
        return grid;
    }
}
```

Then finally the factory looks something like this:

```
public class GridManagerFactory {
    public static AbstractGridManager getGridManager(LifecicleAlgorithmIntrface lifecicleAlgorithm, String... args){
        AbstractGridManager manager = null;

        // input from the command line
        if(args.length == 2){
            CommandLineGridManager clManager = new CommandLineGridManager();
            clManager.setWidth(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            clManager.setHeight(Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
            // possibly more configuration logic
            ...
            manager = clManager;
        } 
        // input from the file
        else if(args.length == 1){
            FileInputGridManager fiManager = new FileInputGridManager();
            fiManager.setFilePath(args[0]);
            // possibly more method calls from abstract class
            ...
            manager = fiManager ;
        }
        //... more possible concrete implementors
        else{
            manager = new CommandLineGridManager();
        }
        manager.setLifecicleAlgorithm(lifecicleAlgorithm);
        return manager;
    }
}
```

The receiver of AbstractGridManager would call the methods on him and get the logic, implemented in the concrete descender (and partially in the abstract class methods) without knowing what is the concrete implementation he got. This is also known as inversion of control or dependency injection.

Answer (score 4):

**You can say:**
 we can't instantiate an abstract class, but we can use `new` keyword to create an anonymous class instance by just adding `{}` as implement body at the the end of the abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

No, we can't create the object of abstract class, but  create the reference variable of the abstract class. The reference variable is used to refer to the objects of derived classes (Sub classes of Abstract class)

Here is the example that illustrates this concept

```
abstract class Figure { 

    double dim1; 

    double dim2; 

    Figure(double a, double b) { 

        dim1 = a; 

        dim2 = b; 

    } 

    // area is now an abstract method 

    abstract double area(); 

    }


    class Rectangle extends Figure { 
        Rectangle(double a, double b) { 
        super(a, b); 
    } 
    // override area for rectangle 
    double area() { 
        System.out.println("Inside Area for Rectangle."); 
        return dim1 * dim2; 
    } 
}

class Triangle extends Figure { 
    Triangle(double a, double b) { 
        super(a, b); 
    } 
    // override area for right triangle 
    double area() { 
        System.out.println("Inside Area for Triangle."); 
        return dim1 * dim2 / 2; 
    } 
}

class AbstractAreas { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        // Figure f = new Figure(10, 10); // illegal now 
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(9, 5); 
        Triangle t = new Triangle(10, 8); 
        Figure figref; // this is OK, no object is created 
        figref = r; 
        System.out.println("Area is " + figref.area()); 
        figref = t; 
        System.out.println("Area is " + figref.area()); 
    } 
}
```

Here we see that we cannot create the object of  type Figure but we can create a reference variable of type Figure. Here we created a reference variable of type Figure and Figure Class reference variable is used to refer to the objects of  Class Rectangle and Triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Actually we can not create an object of an abstract class directly. What we create is a reference variable of an abstract call. The reference variable is used to Refer to the object of the class which inherits the Abstract class i.e. the subclass of the abstract class.