# Instantiating abstract classes in Java: Why does this work?

Tags: java, abstract, extend, inner-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interview : Can we instantiate abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670991/interview-can-we-instantiate-abstract-class)

I have an abstract class with all its methods defined (i.e. there are no abstract methods contained within it) like the following:

```java
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
  String s;
  public void setString(String s) {
    this.s = s;
  }
  public String getString() {
    return this.s;
  }
}
```

There is also a JUnit test class:

```java
public class TestClass {

  MyAbstractClass c;
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    // What is happening here? And why does this work with an abstract class?
    // Instantiation? Extending the abstract class? Overwriting?
    c = new MyAbstractClass() { };
    // This will not work: (Why?)
    // c = new MyAbstractClass();
  }

  @Test
  public void test_AllMethodsAvailable() {
    // Why can I access the abstract class' methods?
    // Shouldn't they be overwritten? Or did I extend the class?
    c.setString("Test");
    assertEquals("Test", c.getString());
  }
}
```

I don't quite understand why the assignment to `c` works in the first case but not in the second, or what is actually happening there (and as a consequence, why accessing the abstract class' methods works in the test).

Can somebody please explain (and possibly point me to a Javadoc, article or book that explains why this works)?

Why can I "instantiate" an abstract class there? (Is that actually what I'm doing?)

Has it to do with inner classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an ***anonymous inner class*** with that code. The class you create this way is implicitly extending `MyAbstractClass`.

Since your `abstract` class does not have `abstract` methods you don't have to provide implementations so this works.

If you don't know about inner classes you can check the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) which is quite nice I think.

Comment: Thanks. Though I think the "overwrite" tag was useful in that others who are new to Java might search for that word if they have a similar problem. I know I did... :)

Answer (score 1):

> Has it to do with inner classes?

```
 c = new MyAbstractClass() { };
```

Absolutely, the above is **anonymous inner class** declaration, you are not really instantiating an abstract class(which you can't) here but you are actually creating an **Anonymous inner class**(`a sub-type of MyAbstractClass`)

Answer (score 0):

When you write `c = new MyAbstractClass() { };`, you actually create an anonymous class which extends `MyAbstractClass`, and which is not abstract. Since `MyAbstractClass` already has all method defined, the instanciation is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment to c works because you are subclassing MyAbstractClass with an anonymous non-abstract class, the c is an instance of the non-abstract class.

Since you don't have any abstract methods in your abstract class, your anonymous class doesn't have to implement anything.