# Comparator interface in java

Tags: java

Comparator is an interface, and I believe it can't be instantiated,but please see the code snippet below

```
Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
                { 
                             //Compare method
                        });
```

Here comparator interface has been instantiated,is this the correct way to code.
Some one please help.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750772/instantiating-interfaces-in-java

Comment: You are not instantiating the interface but rather an anonymous inner class that implements the Comparator interface.

Comment: Thanks Ron,I read the concept of anonymous class and now its clear

Answer (score 3):

This one of the correct ways to implement an interface and this implementation is called [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Note that you're implementing an instance of `Comparator` that cannot be referred as a variable.

Another note: You will have to provide implementation of the

```
public int compareTo(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry1, 
                     Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry2) { .. }
```

method, otherwise it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

This is an acceptable way to code.  The compiler will make your implementation of the `Comparator` interface into a class.  Because you don't provide a name for the class, this is called an anonymous class.

I have no issue with the use of anonymous classes, but I prefer to use a variable, for an instance of an anonymous class.  This gives you the opportunity to supply a name that says what kind of comparison your comparator will do.  In this case, I might write something like this.

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> byValueDescendingThenKey = 
        new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry2) {
        int valueComparison = entry1.getValue().compareTo(entry2.getValue());
        if (valueComparison != 0) {
            return -valueComparison;
        } else {
            return entry1.getKey().compareTo(entry2.getKey());
        }
    }
};

Collections.sort(list,byValueDescendingThenKey);
```

Notice how if there is a nice descriptive name for the variable that references the `Comparator`, the line that does the sorting is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous instance of `Comparator` must satisfy the interface by implementing the `compare` method.  The `Comparator` is a SAM (Single Abstract Method) interface, which allows it to be instantiated via an anonymous class.

```
Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
{ 
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry1, Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry2) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> comparator = new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> arg0, Entry<String, Integer> arg1) {
            // logic here
            return 0;
        }

    };
```

This is how you implement the `Comparator` interface. Obviously you won't return `0`. This construct is called an anonymous inner class. It makes sense if you are only going to use this implementation in one place.

Answer (score 0):

1) You may implement the Comparator in a separate class  and refer to it as a second argument in the Collection.sort() method

2) Or for the second argument, you can put the implementation "in place" i.e.

```
Collections.sort( (Collection) argument,  new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(){ /*your implementation*/}  );
```

which is done through an anonymous class (your case).