# "new Foo(){}" vs. "new Foo()" in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

For example:

```
Object o1 = new ArrayList<String>();
Object o2 = new ArrayList<String>(){};
Object o3 = new ArrayList<String>(){{}};
```

What's the difference?

I can't google out the 2nd/3rd grammar of Java, any reference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interview : Can we instantiate abstract class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670991/interview-can-we-instantiate-abstract-class)

Comment: Third one is declaring an instance initializer block of the anonymous class.

Comment: Re: the third one, http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization

Comment: `new ArrayList<String>(){{{{{{}}}}}}` is still legal :p

Comment: Very interesting to see that third one, what do we call the third notation?

Comment: @SimonT Double-brace initialization, but try to stay away from it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first creates an ArrayList

The second creates an anonymous subclass of ArrayList which has a specific generic type of String

The third is the same but it has a initializer block which is empty.

Note: Where ever possible, you should write the simplest and clearest code you can, esp if you are thinking about performance.

Comment: I think you should add "unless there is a detailed comment explaining that there is some weird special need for an anonymous class to circumvent reflection, the 2nd and 3rd cases are just plain stupid, confusing, and wrong."

Comment: I'll add that [JMock](http://www.jmock.org) uses the third style for it's mocks to subclass and encode expectations.

Answer (score 13):

```
Object o1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Creates an ArrayList.

```
Object o2 = new ArrayList<String>(){};
```

Here you are creating an **anonymous class** that extends `ArrayList<String>` and don't override anything. So the difference it's that you are subclassing an ArrayList without overrding behaviour, **never do this if you don't have a good reason**.

```
Object o3 = new ArrayList<String>(){{}};
```

You are creating the same as 2 but with an empty initalizer block.

Comment: thanks! got it. maybe the second is useful to avoid "type erasure"?

Comment: @marstone. No that's not the use. Type erasure cannot be avoided.

Comment: @RohitJain if not, how could google gson keep the generic parameter type by using "new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType()"? sorry if this is off the topic.

Comment: @marstone they use black magic of reflection, it's unrelated to anonymous subclasses, you can find some details [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained)

Comment: @Katona: It is *absolutely* related to anonymous subclasses; I'm not sure how you can claim otherwise. The subclassing is what allows the type-argument to be available at runtime despite erasure. (Sure, it's only available using the black magic of reflection, but without the subclassing even that much would not be possible.)

Comment: @ruakh, ok, let me correct myself, it is related to _subclassing_ but doesn't have to be anonymous, and certainly doesn't prevent type erasure.

Answer (score 2):

```
Object o1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Creating a new ArrayList object and assigning it to `o1`

```
Object o2 = new ArrayList<String>(){};
```

Creating a new instance of an anonymous class that extends ArrayList and assigning it to `o2`

```
Object o3 = new ArrayList<String>(){{}};
```

Creating a new instance of a (different from `o2`) anonymous class that extends ArrayList that has a no-op instance initializer.

Functionally the anon classes assigned to `o2` and `o3` are equivalent but technically they will be different classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are anonymously instantiating a class. You could override methods in the later case without the need to define a new class in an own file.

Answer (score 0):

`o3` is still an instance of an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList` which has an empty instance initialization block (the inner `{}`).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Instantiate an object of type `ArrayList<String>`
Object o1 = new ArrayList<String>();

// Instantiate an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList<String>`
Object o2 = new ArrayList<String>(){};

// Instantiate an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList<String>` with an empty initializer block
Object o3 = new ArrayList<String>(){{}};
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object o2 = new ArrayList<String>(){};`
it is *annonymous inner class* that extends `ArrayList` class and overrides nothing.
`Object o2 = new ArrayList<String>(){{}};`
it is also *annonymous inner class* that extends `ArrayList` class and overrides nothing but has a `empty instance block`.