# Cannot instantiate the type userSQLOpenHelper and I do not know why

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my MainActivity.java I get this error "Cannot instantiate the type userSQLOpenHelper". at new userSQLOpenHelper(this). Can someone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong?

MainActivity.java

```
userSQLOpenHelper db = new userSQLOpenHelper(this);             
// add user
db.addUser(new user(name1,born1,sex,passwd,email1));
```

user.java

```
public final class user {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String born;
    private String sex;
    private int password;
    private String email;

        // This is recommended to prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the user class,
    public user() {}

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public user(String name, String born, String sex, int password, String email)      {
        // super();
        this.name = name;
        this.born = born;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "user [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", born=" + born + ", sex=" + sex + ", password=" + password
            + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBorn(){
        return this.born;
    }

    public void setBorn(String born){
        this.born = born;
    }

      public String getSex(){
        return this.sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex){
        this.sex = sex;
    }

      public int getPassword(){
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(int password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

userSQLOpenHelper.java

```
public abstract class userSQLOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Table name
    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

    // Table Columns names
    private static final String USER_ID = "id";
    private static final String USER_NAME = "name";
    private static final String USER_BORN = "born";
    private static final String USER_SEX = "sex";
    private static final String USER_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String USER_EMAIL = "email";

    //private static final String[] COLUMNS = {USER_ID,USER_NAME,USER_BORN,USER_SEX,USER_PASSWORD,USER_EMAIL};

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userDB";   

  public userSQLOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
  }


    @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL statement to create user table
    String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE users ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
            "name TEXT NOT NULL, "+ 
            "born TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "sex TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "password INTERGER NOT NULL, " +
            "email TEXT NOT NULL )";

    // create books table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);

  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older books table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books");

    // create fresh books table
    this.onCreate(db);
  }


  public void addUser(user user){
    SQLiteDatabase db;
     //get reference to writable DB
     db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(USER_NAME, user.getName()); 
    values.put(USER_BORN, user.getBorn()); 
    values.put(USER_SEX, user.getSex()); 
    values.put(USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword()); 
    values.put(USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail()); 

      // insert
    db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values); 

    // close
    db.close(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: see [Interview: Can we instantiate abstract class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670991/interview-can-we-instantiate-abstract-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate `abstract` classes...

```
public abstract class userSQLOpenHelper
```

Since you do not have any `abstract` methods inside your class, you can just remove the keyword `abstract` from your class declaration and that error should disappear...

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your class abstract.

Remove that keyword from your userSQLOpenHelper class declaration.